# Previously working discord bots stopped working after pip update

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, discord.py

First of all, sorry for the vague question, tbf I really don't know how to title this either

So I have a few bots that I own, and another bot made by someone else, that bot in question randomly stopped working so I updated it and it updated dependencies along with it
Pretty sure it updated something to do with -pip

Since then none of my bots have been working anymore, simple stuff like `await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)` doesn't work anymore, says :

```
line 30, in on_message
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Which has always worked before, so it shouldn't be something wrong with the code

```
line 170, in on_message
    await client.delete_message(message)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'delete_message'
```

and

My bots also can't seem to delete messages or change presence, respectively

```
 line 23, in on_ready
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='m!help',type = 3))
TypeError: change_presence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'game'
```

I am completely clueless as to what i'm supposed to do to fix my problem since I did not change anything within the code themselves

This might be important since it's mentioned in the codes I have above but here's what I have for "client" `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "m!")`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you using?  Try `import discord; print(discord.__version__)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh appologies for the long delay, was sleepy time. -

`print(discord._version__version__` prints "1.0.0a"

Comment: You installed the newer "rewrite" branch, which [changed the way messages are sent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#sending-messages). You can either rewrite your code for the rewrite branch, or downgrade back to the 0.16 async release.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I see, thank you for telling me, was pretty lost
I'll look into both options and see what suits me best

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I haven't been able to find any information on how to downgrade back to the 0.16 async release, could u perharps  guide me in the correct direction if that's possible ?

Comment: `pip` should by default install the async 0.16.12 branch using `python -m pip install discord`. If that doesn't work, then you can download it manually and use pip to install it from your local hard drive. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the other bot I had independently updating to the newer rewrite brand, as pointed out by PatrickHaugh in the comments above

To fix this issue I had to unistall every pip by runnin `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y`

And then reinstalling the older async release by runnin `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py`

Answer (score -1):

Try change your `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "m!")` to `client = discord.Client()`
I think it's can solve all your problem.

Comment: that didn't fix the issue sadly, it came up with basically the same error : 
`AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'`

Comment: It's weird. Have you forgot parenthesis ? Did you use discord.py or discord.py-rewrite ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm simply using discord.py and not rewrite

And no, I included the parenthesis