# bot doesnt respond after used pip

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I needed to use pip to upgrade discord.py to use the timeout method
as said in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70593496/18837888

after that i relaunched my bot and it starts fine but when i run a command it doesn't respond but i don't get any error i don't know what to do,
i tried to unistall as said in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53237075/18837888
but it did work

Comment: It's probably your intents.

Comment: @3nws explain more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not what to do, if you are trying to get the latest discord.py version which is 2.0

First to install it you need to do

```
pip uninstall discord.py
```

or you can go to your files and

`C:Users/PC NAME/AppData/Roaming/Python/python310(or your current version)/site-packages`

Then from there delete the folders that say `Discord`, and `discord.distinfo`

Once those are deleted, do

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

then you will have the latest version!
Make sure to have git installed you can install it from [HERE](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

Hope this helped